# Get alias values from Wikidata for a given property?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

For a given property like ['occupation (P106)'](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P106), I want to retrieve all its aliases like: profession, job, work, career, employment, craft. All of this is present on the properties wikidata page, under 'Also known as'. How can I go about retrieving this using SPARQL?
I tried using the following query.

```
  SELECT ?predicate ?object WHERE {
  wdt:P106 wdt:P1449 ?predicate .  //Nickname
  wdt:P106 wdt:P734 ?predicate .   //Family Name
  wdt:P106 wdt:P735 ?predicate .  //Given Name
  wdt:P106 skos:altLabel ?predicate . 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Comment: The OP neglected to link to the page containing class=wikibase-entitytermsview-aliases-alias that he wants to scrape: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P106

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sql
SELECT ?altLabel
{
 VALUES (?wd) {(wd:P106)}
 ?wd skos:altLabel ?altLabel .
 FILTER (lang(?altLabel) = "en")
}
```

or

```sql
SELECT ?altLabel
{
 VALUES (?wdt) {(wdt:P106)}
 ?wd wikibase:directClaim ?wdt .
 ?wd skos:altLabel ?altLabel .
 FILTER (lang(?altLabel) = "en")
}
```

These paragraphs provide some explanation:

- [Truthy statements](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements)
- [Properties](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Properties)
- [Predicates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Predicates)

---

**Update**

You still could use the label service:

```sql
SELECT ?wdAltLabel
{
 VALUES (?wdt) {(wdt:P106)}
 ?wd wikibase:directClaim ?wdt .
 SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```