# How to get "Also known as" in German and English

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have created a query for wikidata which I am satisfied with so far. I didn't manage to retrieve the "also known as" data as can be seen at 
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q251347. It would be really great to get these data in German and English. Also with the basic label it would be great to have English as an additional column.
I've already found questions with a similar topic here, but the answers don't seem to be transferable to the drugs.

```
SELECT ?Arzneimittel ?ATC_Code ?CAS_Nummer ?UNII ?Drugbank_ID ?EG_Nummer ?ArzneimittelLabel WHERE {
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de". }
      ?Arzneimittel wdt:P31 wd:Q12140.
      OPTIONAL { ?Arzneimittel wdt:P267 ?ATC_Code. }
      OPTIONAL { ?Arzneimittel wdt:P231 ?CAS_Nummer. }
      OPTIONAL { ?Arzneimittel wdt:P652 ?UNII. }
      OPTIONAL { ?Arzneimittel wdt:P715 ?Drugbank_ID. }
      OPTIONAL { ?Arzneimittel wdt:P232 ?EG_Nummer. }
    }
    LIMIT 1000000
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46439981/7879193 ?